# Method of breaking a long line sentence

Tags: html, css, iphone, word-wrap

I'm developing an iPhone theme for my website, can you be able to break a long sentence something like this:

```
A long sentence would go past the iPhone screen and I need this to break
```

Into this:

```
A long sentence would go past the iPhone
screen and I need this to break
```

Showing like this:

http://uimgz.com/i/M8U5X5f2d1.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if your text has spaces then adding a width for the wrap element will break the text automatically. But if you have a text without a space (such as a link) you can use `break-word`:

```
.your-selector {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

As per: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Browser_compatibility

```
pre {
  word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE 5.5-7 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox 1.0-2.0 */
  white-space: pre-wrap;      /* current browsers */
}
```

`word-wrap` doesn't seem to work any more, use `white-space` instead

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the "viewport" is wider than the device's screen.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230019/how-to-set-viewport-meta-for-iphone-that-handles-rotation-properly) for some background and possible solution.