# How can I fix this mobile stylesheet bug for iPhones and ipods?

Tags: css, html, media-queries

This is how my mobile stylesheet looks on a live iphone device: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0b1l8g51a , the website url can be seen in the adressbar, it looks fine on ipod/iphone from the second generation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@user257357; it's not only problem of your `ipad & ipod` version it also have a problem in your `PC` version. Just test when you decrease your window size.

solution

css:

iphone & ipad

```
body{
 min-width:480px;
}
```

css:

PC

```
body{
 min-width:966px;
}
```

check this for more [iPad background for div blocks not spanning entire width of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708203/ipad-background-for-div-blocks-not-spanning-entire-width-of-screen/5775968#5775968)

Comment: Thanks for the answer SAndeep, done , however not working and I still can't figure out why, I even tried it with the width:100% just to check, still not working, any advice? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that this

```
width:100%;
```

will do the job better.