# How to set changable width ( div with background ) to make look good on different devices?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap. Here is my problem: I need to set div's background color,which should be full screen, but when I try :

and my HTML:

```
    <div class="rowHome">
      <div class="container">  
       <div class="row">
     ...
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

and full CSS:

```
    .container{
    width: 960px;       
}
    ...
     .rowHome{
margin-top:10px;
width:100%;
background-color:#400143;
}
```

it look like this, when I resize page:

[image]

but when I scroll right I see the bug:

[image]

Can someone tell me where is my error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of problem is mostly come when the `parent` have **flexible width** & his `child` have **fixed width**. Write this in your css:

```
body{
  min-width:960px;
}
```

Check this for more [iPad background for div blocks not spanning entire width of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708203/ipad-background-for-div-blocks-not-spanning-entire-width-of-screen/5775968#5775968)