# Bootstrap background full width divs displaying incorrectly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, mobile-safari

I have a built a site for a New Zealand non-profit. It's based on Bootstrap 3 with responsive features disabled. It's working well... except for the way that the background images for outer divs display on mobile Safari.
Here is an example of the code:

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="columns go here">
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.top {
    height: 47px; 
    background-color: #000;
}
```

But when I view the site using mobile Safari the wrapper div (.top) does not appear to fill the full width of the screen.

Here's the site: http://betterbroadcasting.co.nz/

And here's a screengrab from mobile Safari: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35912963/IMG_2746.PNG

I'd really appreciate any insight into what I may be doing wrong here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a meta viewport tag?

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Otherwise experiment with changing `min-width` as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708203/ipad-background-for-div-blocks-not-spanning-entire-width-of-screen).

Comment: According to the Bootstrap non-responsive template example page here http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/ there's no need for the meta viewport tag. But having read the thread you linked to I have added min-width to the full-width divs, at the same value as the container div. Thank you for your help!