# JQuery Mobile: Page to zoomed out

Tags: jquery-mobile

My jquery mobile page is WAY to zoomed out. I have tried everything I can think of, but I cant get it to zoom in.

This is the last thing I have been trying:

```
.ui-mobile-viewport {
    max-height: 440px !important;
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

How do you zoom in a page? I just want the page to fit normally on the phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the viewport meta tag: http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/viewport-metatag

EDIT:

Perhaps I don't fully understand the problem, but maybe you could try to fix it within the following CSS @media queries:

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* set some widths maybe? */
}

@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* second verse same as the first */
}
```

Finally, if I'm still off base, do the answers here help? [How to set viewport meta for iPhone that handles rotation properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230019/how-to-set-viewport-meta-for-iphone-that-handles-rotation-properly)

Comment: Are you starting from the jQuery mobile html templates? They all include: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Could it be missing from your template?

Comment: That zooms it in, but everything is shifted to the right off screen. It fixes itself when I move the phone to landscape and back, but it wont fix itself on its own

Comment: Its grabbing landscape width reguardless of orientation if that helps

Comment: Those don't work, because editing the width throws everything off. I made a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629236/jquery-mobile-grabbing-landscape-width-on-load-when-phone-is-in-portrait that better explains what is going on