# JQuery Mobile: Grabbing landscape width on load when phone is in portrait

Tags: jquery-mobile

My mobile app is grabbing the land-scape width of teh phone when it is in protrait mode. How do I fix this?

To be more specific: if i load the application and I am in portrait view, it will load a landscape view, which is pushing everything to the right. If I load the page when in landscape view everything works.

If I load the app in portrait view then move it to landscape and back, the portrait view is fine. It's just the initial load up.

Also this did not always happen, in fact it did not start happening until today.

I have been doing: 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

but that doesn't work (because it thinks the phone is in landscape)

I have 0 clue what to do here. Is there a way to force the app to jump from landscape or reload once, then find the orientation?

**Edit** I can pick up the orientation like so:

```
       if (window.orientation == 0) {
            alert("portrait");
        } else {
            alert("landscape");
        }
```

How can I edit the code to make sure the portrait css is showing from here?

Comment: Just curious, what is the model of the phone?

Comment: Droid X. It doesnt work on other droids i have tested either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is it? http://www.roccles.com/?p=140

Just for testing, modify the first few lines of that javascript to this:

```
if(window.orientation == 0){
    var ori = "portrait";
}else{
    var ori = "landscape";
}

alert(ori);
```

I'm curious what alert you get on your initial page load.

Comment: I get the correct orientations for those, (I added in my edit) Apparently it is fine on iPhones as well

Comment: The actual problem was that it was a facebook app, and their updates killed it. Thanks for all the help though

Comment: Glad you got to botom of it, but sorry you have to deal with facebook bugs. They're better than any hacker at screwing other people's stuff up...

Comment: You should use media queries for checking orientation.