# How to zoom out website build for tablet on smartphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, zooming, viewport

I developed a website for 1024x768 and used the following viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=768, initial-scale=1" />
```

It looks great on desktop and tablet, but when I view on the iPhone it's zoomed in. I can double tap to view the entire website and then it looks great too. But is there a way so that on the iPhone will immediately view the zoomed out version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use width=device-width for portrait orientation. Otherwise you must use media queries for each proposed width view device (for landscape position).

Comment: Device-width didn't help... I was kinda hoping I wouldn't have to do media queries for the proposed screen sizes.

Comment: Unfortunately you have [to](http://tech.bluesmoon.info/2011/01/device-width-and-how-not-to-hate-your.html)

Comment: Can't i like simulate a double tap to get the desired effect? :p

Comment: Maybe this would help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230019/how-to-set-viewport-meta-for-iphone-that-handles-rotation-properly