# Changing Metatag keywords with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyword, meta-tags

I got a question, its possible to change the Metatag Keywords with JQuery?

I Already tried this but didn't work.

```
$("meta").attr("description", "Keywords bla bla bla");
```

And this

```
$('meta[name=keywords]').attr('content', 'New Author Name');
```

Any solution?

Comment: meta tags are used as static content by, for example: google, search engines primarily, and are used to know some words that you think are important for indexing the given site. You need to do this on the server.

Comment: 'Cause its a CMS and i want to manage the Dynamic Content

Comment: @FelipeLeñero: But meta tags aren't read by the browser, they're read by search engines.  Using JavaScript to change them doesn't do anything, and serves no purpose.

Comment: Your second example should work, but it's pointless since META tags are used when the page loads and your editing the tags after the load.

Comment: Ohhh, well that explains everything.
Thanks a lot! Regards!

Comment: EVERYBODY REPEAT AFTER ME: META TAGS ARE STATIC CONTENT. JAVASCRIPT IS FOR DYNAMICS.

Comment: @jcolebrand: "AFTER ME: META TAGS ARE STATIC CONTENT. JAVASCRIPT IS FOR DYNAMICS.".

Comment: That's correct what @Rocket said. Crawlers wont be able to run js. Altho, there are some meta tags used by browsers. Like [iPhone scale and rotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230019/how-to-set-viewport-meta-for-iphone-that-handles-rotation-properly)

Comment: @Vizualni: True, though I'm not sure if anything would happen if you changed them with JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole purpose of metatags is to help searchers. If you load them via JS searchers (spiders)  wont read them, and there is no point in having them

Comment: specifically: "spiders can't load javascript content, ever"

Answer (score 0):

I did experiment with this to psyche out Facebook's Open Graph, and turns out meta tags are loaded before JS, kind of mooting the entire idea.