# Webpage has a large right-margin in iOS

Tags: html, css, ios, ios-simulator, mobile-safari

I have checked everything on my page and cannot figure out what is giving my website a large right-margin in iOS. It's driving me crazy. I've tried setting overflow: hidden; on the body to no avail. There is nothing that is wider than 960px. This is a very responsive design and all is working well except this one infuriating thing. Here is the URL to the dev site: http://ourcityourstory.com/dev/

Please see attached screenshot: [image: iOS displaying large right-margin on webpage]

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:** I've tried fooling with the viewport. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230019/how-to-set-viewport-meta-for-iphone-that-handles-rotation-properly) Stackoverflow post. But to no avail. I built the entire site off of the [HTML 5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com)

Comment: @biziclop Did you drag right? It renders full screen and fine, but there is a horizontal scroll bar if you drag left or right.

Comment: It is not draggable left or right in: iOS Simulator 4.3: iPhone 4.0.2, 4.3, iPhone simulator 3.1: iPhone 3.1.2 Didn't you updated it since your question?

Comment: I'm seeing it on my iPhone and iOS Simulator. I'm running 5.1.

Answer (score 3):

```
       html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

Add this to your CSS. then it should be working fine

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was the Facebook share button. Instead of behaving like Twitter or Pinterest it iframes in and sets a width on the body of 500px!

A simple `overflow: hidden;` on my `.social` class fixed this.