# Black bar on iPad after setting viewport

Tags: ipad, xhtml, meta, joomla3.0

Site address: straightace.com

Used the following code:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,
                    user-scalable=yes,maximum-scale=0.6,width=device-width"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width">
```

The intent was to have the 1085 px wide page load in any iPad oriented vertically or horizontally, we have a separate script for any device under 699px wide that redirects to a mobile site and are not worried about Android tablets at the moment. Everything goes smoothly when loading the page in either orientation and even when loading horizontally and turning to vertical.

The problem is when loading the page in vertical orientation and turning it to horizontal, the page pushes to the left and a large black bar appears on the right hand side of the screen. Upon refreshing, the bar disappears.

Can anyone help with removing the black bar while retaining the functionality of the viewport?

Answer (score 0):

This code might be of help:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height, initial-scale=.5">
```

That is, remove the `maximum-scale` attribute from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
```

While simple, this solution effectively disables pinch-zooming.  There are various Javascript solutions that fix this rotating viewport issue while still allowing the user to zoom.  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8119519/445295) works for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function( doc ){
    var addEvent = 'addEventListener',
     type = 'gesturestart',
     qsa = 'querySelectorAll',
     scales = [1, 1],
     meta = qsa in doc ? doc[qsa]( 'meta[name=viewport]' ) : [];
    function fix(){
        meta.content = 'width=device-width,minimum-scale=' + scales[0] + ',maximum-scale=' + scales[1];
        doc.removeEventListener( type, fix, true );
    }
    if( (meta = meta[meta.length - 1]) && addEvent in doc ){
        fix();
        scales = [.25, 1.6];
        doc[addEvent]( type, fix, true );
    }
}( document ));
</script>
```