# Forcing a page to be displayed entirely on any smartphone without having to zoom out

Tags: html, viewport

According to my client, [this page I made for him](http://goo.gl/4Vmkx0) appears "zoomed in" when viewed for the first time on his smartphone (not on mine though), forcing him to zoom out.

In the meta tags I used:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1050, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
```

Is there a way to make sure the page will be displayed entirely on any smartphone without the need to zoom out?

Comment: the top answer here should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230019/how-to-set-viewport-meta-for-iphone-that-handles-rotation-properly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `width=1050` part. If the mobile display is narrower than that, the page will be zoomed-in. Also, you need to set a `minimum-scale` value.

Try with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

If your content **needs** to be `1050px` wide, then I'm afraid it's not ready for mobile.

### Update after reading the comment to the original answer

Ok, then you need to change the `initial-scale` value in your original code.

Comment: I don't want the page to me mobile friendly. I want it to be displayed in its entirety on the smartphone screen, with the user having to zoom IN (not OUT) to read normal sized characters.