# Webpage can be dragged to left and zoomed in / out in mobile view

Tags: iphone, html, css

I am working on a webpage at work and I am facing an issue that my webpage can be dragged to left when viewing on a mobile device.

I do have this meta tag on my website

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

However this does not fix the issue.

Unfortunately due to company policies I cannot share the code here.

I have checked that nothing is overflowing.

I also have the overflow-x set to hidden on my body tag.

The user is unable to scroll (No scrollbars appear) but he is able to drag the page to the left and zoom-out.

Comment: Check this post:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230019/how-to-set-viewport-meta-for-iphone-that-handles-rotation-properly][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230019/how-to-set-viewport-meta-for-iphone-that-handles-rotation-properly

Comment: I tried that, it did not help, the user can still drag the page to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change , to ; in:

```
"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
```

Comment: Look also on this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345896/full-webpage-and-disabled-zoom-viewport-meta-tag-for-all-mobile-browsers/12270403#12270403)

Comment: width=device-width:initial-scale=1.0;maximum-scale=1.0 ;user-scalable=no

Comment: I did that, same thing it still is able to drag to the left, sorry i know its a pain and thank you so much for helping me !

Comment: The link that you sent me is great, I will try all these first and then get back.

Comment: I actually fixed it using the link you sent me. Thank you