# How to switch mobile to desktop screen on Mobile view on actual view website with just one click?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, meta-tags

I already had this working for most phone but for some reason iPhones will not work.

I've create a button and changes the meta tag with jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#desktopversion").click(function(){
        $('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=1380, initial-scale=0');
    });
    $("#nvs").click(function(){
        $('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=1380, initial-scale=0');
    });
});
```

But for some reason, the page gets cut off on iPhone

[image]

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230019/how-to-set-viewport-meta-for-iphone-that-handles-rotation-properly this might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Please read this article ,its may be help you

https://webdevdoor.com/responsive-web-design/change-viewport-meta-tag-javascript

```
if (screen.width <= 480) {
 document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", "width=480; initial-scale=0.5");
}
```

Comment: I've tried it, it is now zoomed in but still cut off.. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: Okay, I've checked it ones more and it is kind of working. You get zoomed in with the initial-scale of 0.5. If you swipe down, it will show the rest of the website, but if you scale the page with 2 thumbs, it keeps cut off. I hope this is clear enough since it is hard to explain, haha.